# Does this converge?

Tags: probability, convergence-divergence, probability-limit-theorems

If I have 
$$X_i=\begin{cases}2\quad p=\frac{1}{3}\\
\frac{1}{2}\quad p=\frac{2}{3}
\end{cases}$$ 
random variables with the same distribution. How can I compute
the limit almost sure as $n\to\infty$ of
$\prod_{i=1}^nX_i$?
I just need a hint. Thanks.

Comment: The sum of the probabilities is greater than $1$; is there a typing problem?

Answer (score 1):

In this solution, I assume that $P\left(X_i=2\right)=\frac{1}{3}$. In this case, define $Y_i=\log_2 X_i$; then
$$Y_i=\left\{\begin{matrix}1,&p=\frac{1}{3}\\-1,&p=\frac{2}{3}\end{matrix}\right.$$
Obviously,
$$\prod_{i=1}^n X_i=2^{\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i}$$
so it is enough to check the sum of $Y_i$. Now, can you prove what their sum is a.s.?

Comment: yes, now I would say that for the law of lrge number everything is going to $0$. Is it correct?

Comment: Yes; By the SLLN, $\frac{1}{n}\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\to E\left[Y_i\right]=-\frac{1}{3}$, so we must have $\sum_{i=1}^n Y_i\to-\infty$ a.s., so the product tends to $0$ a.s.